# Change specific color to another in a PDF file

Tags: color, pdf

I have a PDF file whose objects' color are either pure Cyan or pure Black or a tint of them (30% Cyan or 50% Black, for example). The objects include texts, line strokes and vector fills.

Now, how may I change the Cyan color (and all the tints, of course) to another color, lets say to Green! It's for presentations only, so any workaround is greatly appreciated :)

---

<sup>**P.S:** Actually I've created the file using *InDesign*; and of course I can change the colors there, but the files include an *immense* number of linked EPS files (Math expressions) *that would need to be modified manually*! and since it's for presentations, it doesn't worth the time. Also; after each modification, the required color conversion needs to be done again to create an updated file for an updated presentation! So it defines the need. I do have access to Adobe Acrobat Pro, but I'm not restricted to the Acrobat Pro, any other tool is also welcome :)

**P.S:** The initial colors (the Cyan and the Black) are the final colors; and that's OK! Nevertheless, the colors need to be changed *for presentation purposes only* :)</sup>

Comment: Could you provide some more information? It's quite difficult to give specific answers without details of which software you have access to, and perhaps let us know which software was used to create the PDF if possible, also do you have access to the original file?

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I don't believe Acrobat offers the ability to swap colors.

You can assign profiles and manage ink percentages/angles, but not change ink definitions entirely.

Ideally, you edit the originating document if you want different colors.

Answer (score 0):

Export to EPS and use a text editor (best: vim) to replace the color.
E.g. execute 
:%s/0 1 0 rgb/0 0.5 0 rgb/ 
in vim to replace (light) green by a darker one.
Afterwards create a PDF from the EPS.